# Swiftui 3 API cleanup: is it achievable with custom styles?

Tags: swiftui

Swiftui 3 and iOS15 gave us the possibility to use styling more easily, so instead of

```
.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
```

we might use

```
.pickerStyle(.wheel)
```

At the same time, we can determine custom styles, for example:

```
struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12).fill(Color.red))
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.9 : 1.0)
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
    }
}
```

However, to use the above custom style, I have to write

```
.buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle())
```

How might I achieve the possibility to use the custom style with a simple modifier like this?

```
.buttonStyle(.custom)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create extension to `ButtonStyle`, like

```
extension ButtonStyle where Self == CustomButtonStyle {
    static var custom: CustomButtonStyle { CustomButtonStyle() }
}
```

and then use it as

```
.buttonStyle(.custom)
```

Tested with Xcode 13 / iOS15

*Note: this approach does not work with Xcode 12*